# How can I name my OSGi component by using the class name?

Tags: java, osgi

My project uses a convention to use the `class.getName()` as the name for the OSGi container. Most existing components have a `public static final String` constant that contains the name like this:

```
package mypackage;
@Component(name = MyClass.COMPONENT_NAME)
public class MyClass {
    public static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "mypackage" + ".MyClass";
    ...
}
```

When creating my first component in the project I tried this:

```
package mypackage;
@Component(name = MyClass.COMPONENT_NAME)
public class MyClass {
    public static final String COMPONENT_NAME = MyClass.class.getName();
    ...
}
```

However, the compiler complains in the annotation that the `name` should be a constant.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case is is method call which will be executed when class will be initialized (in runtime). 
Value of

> MyClass.class.getName()

method call is not know at compile time. This is reason of complain.

Comment: Yes. COMPONENT_NAME is not a compile-time constant which is necessary for annotations. It is only a runtime constant. Also, for the OSGi DS annotations, if name is not specified, the name of the Component is the fully qualified type name of the class being anno tated. This seems to be what you want anyway.